# Android Studio passing a string from bundle to a method

Tags: android

Retrieved the data i wanted from bundle but how to pass it to a method inside OnClickListener. The retrieveID in addMedical(retrieveID) is in error.

```py
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        if(bundle != null){
            final String retrieveName = getArguments().getString("name");
            patientName.setText(retrieveName);
            final String retrieveIC = getArguments().getString("ic");
            patientIC.setText(retrieveIC);
            final String retrieveID = getArguments().getString("id");

        }else {
        }

        add = v.findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addMedical(retrieveID);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the variables outside the if condition. Make it as class variable.